# PHP Gallery code capping my amount of images displayed

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with a plugin for a wordpress theme I am using by [ThemeChills](http://themechills.com) and the author -- Leo, has given me permission to post his code here in order to find a solution as he is out of town and cannot help me at the moment.

The problem is, my photo gallery thumbnails being generated on the main content of the page are being capped out at 10 visible thumbnails ([link](http://www.brytdesigns.com/floralsandevents/#gallery)). I have uploaded over 100 photos utilizing the correct method according to the author.

I am decent at editing PHP but not proficient enough to find a fix for this -- anyone have any ideas?

```
<?php
 /**
 * Foundation Clearing Shortcode
 *
 * Enables Foundation Clearing Gallery custom post type for 
 * use in the Eternity WordPress Theme by ThemeChills.
 *
 * @package Chills Plugins
 * @author ThemeChills
 */
 ?>
<?php

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  REGISTER POST TYPE
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_action('init', 'chills_photo_gallery_init');

function chills_photo_gallery_init() {

// Photos custom post type
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Photos', 'chills' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Photo', 'chills' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Photo', 'chills' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Photo', 'chills' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Photo', 'chills' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Photos', 'chills' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Photo', 'chills' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Photos', 'chills' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No slides found', 'chills' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No slides found in the Trash', 'chills' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Photos'
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => false,  
    'show_ui'            => true,  
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'rewrite'            => array("slug" => "photo"),  
    'hierarchical'       => false,  
    'rewrite'            => true,  
    'supports'           => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')  
);

register_post_type('photo', $args );
 }

 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    */
 /* FOUNDATION CLEARING SHORTCODE
 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

 /**
 * This implements the functionality of the Foundation Clearing Shortcode 
 * for displaying photos on custom post type.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param array $attr Attributes of the shortcode.
 * @return string HTML content to display photos.
 */

add_shortcode('chills_photo_gallery', 'chills_photo_gallery_shortcode');

function chills_photo_gallery_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',
), $atts));

//comma separated user input IDs to array
$post_include = isset($include) && $include != '' ? explode( ',', $include) : '' ;
$post_exclude = isset($exclude) && $exclude != '' ? explode( ',', $exclude) : '' ;

$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'           => 'photo',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'post__in'            => $post_include, //array
            'post__not_in'        => $post_exclude, //array
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        ));

$html = ''; 

if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    $html .= '<ul class="clearing-thumbs" data-clearing>';

                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                        // define the variables
                        $featured_img       = get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'full' );
                        $featured_img_title = get_the_title();

                        $thumbnail_id       = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
                        $thumbnail_object   = get_post($thumbnail_id);
                        $thumbnail_src      = $thumbnail_object->guid;

                        $html.='<li><a href="'.$thumbnail_src.'">'.$featured_img.'<span class="overlay-label">'.$featured_img_title.'</span></a></li>';

                    endwhile; //END loop

    $html .= '</ul>';

endif;

return $html;

}

?>
```

Comment: obviously not necessarily an option, he won't be back for a while -- otherwise this post wouldn't be here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the code block that begins with `$the_query =` add `'posts_per_page' => -1` to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone had a hard time finding where to make this edit here is a screenshot of the authors suggested fix on ThemeForrest.

[image]